# IndexedDB operations never complete in Safari 13.1

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, safari, indexeddb

I have an Angular app using IndexedDB to store audio video files. This app has been working for 3 years without issue. After upgrading my Macbook to Catalina all operations in IndexedDB never finish executing on the second use. The first time the app run everything works as expected but the second time anytime an IndexedDB function is used nothing happens and the app just hangs. This only happens in Safari 13.1, in Chrome on Macbook it works fine. Is this a known bug?

Comment: What's more strange is this only happens if AOT is used, in debug it works fine for Safari 13.1.